# iOS map view in table view cell wrong frame origin

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I need to set the position of my map view in a table view cell. I simply set the frame in cellForRow method.

some of the map views are misplaced. When I scroll up the table and scroll down to let it reappear (to reuse the table cell), then it is fixed.

Note

1. the y position is wrong but the x position is correct.
2. I use the same way (simply set frame) to set the pictures position and they are always correct. So the problem is map view itself instead of how to position the frame.

The following screenshot shows 3 map views, the middle one has a wrong y position

[image]

EDIT:

The UI part is quite complicated. inside cellForRowAtIndexPath method, I dequeue a MessageCell and call its setupWithMessage:(Message *)message method and then I check if the message is of type location: (a location type message has an optional text view and a map view)

```
        self.textView.hidden = NO;
        self.mapView.hidden = NO;

        self.textView.text = message.text;


        [Helper setupMapView:self.mapView posx:message.posx posy:message.posy];

        CGSize size1 = [UIHelper sizeWithText:message.text entity:message];
        CGSize size2 = [UIHelper sizeWithMapEntity:message];

        CGRect frame = [UIHelper adjustTextView:self.textView textViewSize:size1 extraView:self.mapView extraViewSize:size2 entity:message];








+ (CGRect)adjustTextView:(UITextView *)textView textViewSize:(CGSize)textViewSize extraView:(UIView *)extraView extraViewSize:(CGSize)extraViewSize entity:(id)entity {


    if (textView == nil || extraView == nil || CGSizeEqualToSize(textViewSize, CGSizeZero) || CGSizeEqualToSize(extraViewSize, CGSizeZero)) {
        CGSize targetSize;
        UIView *targetView;

        if (textView == nil || CGSizeEqualToSize(textViewSize, CGSizeZero)) {

            targetView = extraView;
            targetSize = extraViewSize;

        }
        else {
            targetView = textView;
            targetSize = textViewSize;
        }

        return [self adjustContentView:targetView size:targetSize entity:entity];

    }

    else {

        CGRect frame1 = [self adjustContentView:textView size:textViewSize entity:entity];
        CGRect frame2 = [self adjustContentView:extraView size:extraViewSize entity:entity];

        frame2.origin.y += frame1.size.height + OFFSET_BETWEEN_TEXTVIEW_EXTRAVIEW;
        extraView.frame = frame2;

        return CGRectMake(frame1.origin.x, frame1.origin.y, MAX(frame1.size.width, frame2.size.width), frame1.size.height + frame2.size.height + OFFSET_BETWEEN_TEXTVIEW_EXTRAVIEW);
    }
```

Note that the "extraView" above can refer to any view below a text view, such as an UIImageView

```
+ (CGRect)adjustContentView:(UIView *)contentView size:(CGSize) size entity:(id)entity {

    float photoSideOffset = 60;
    float topOffset = 30;

    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.y = topOffset;
    frame.size = size;

    if ([DBHelper isMyEntity:entity]) {
        frame.origin.x = 320 - size.width - photoSideOffset;
    }
    else {
        frame.origin.x = photoSideOffset;
    }
    contentView.frame = frame;


    if ([contentView isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
        [(UITextView *)contentView sizeToFit];
    }

    return contentView.frame;
}
```

EDIT 2: i use the same UIHelper methods for photo messages and the coordinates are correct:

[image]

EDIT 3: the value of size1 size2 and frame

[image]

Comment: Can you please post the code where you're setting the frame?

Comment: Which kind of UITableViewCell are you using?. Usually for something like this I would create a custom cell on storyboard, create a subclass of UItableViewCell and link everything together. I works for me for inserting PickerViews, for example.

Comment: This is a simple problem of view reusability. To give you a hint here, look at the visible portion of first cell & the map position on the middle one. Please post your code & let us know, if you are using it via storyboard or custom views.

Comment: Also your auto layout and auto resizing masks' usage may have something to do. Which one are you using?

Comment: @VinnyCoyne I posted the code

Comment: @Marcal i use a custom nib file for message cell. I believe a custom cell in the storyboard is the same

Comment: @Rivera I don't use auto resizing, frames are customized using code

Comment: @OMGPOP I have given an sample code, with 4 map in row by row..
take a look, may you get help..

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot when the map view looks as you want it to? Also, set the property (Clip to Bounds) of the cell view to YES so that the any subviews in a cell don't go out of its bounds.

Answer (score 3):

**Approach 1:** alloc init UITableViewCell inside your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Simple solution is to  `cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]init];` alloc init every time 
(it will make new cell each time instead caching/or reusing )

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        // Configure the cell...

       /*
        if (cell == nil) {

            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        }

       */
      // Try below code

      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]init];


        ------

        -------

        return cell;

    }
```

**Approach 2:** removeFromSuperView

```
  for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews) {

        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) { // set kind as per your own requirement

            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }


    }
```

Comment: using non-reusable cells is NOT the suitable approach since it's a chatting app thus there may be many cells, with each cell possibly containing rich media which is slow when alloc and dealloc

Comment: @OMGPOP - Have you Measured performance with Instruments - i have tested in my app - i have no performance issue --- Even after that it persists then Approach 2 needs to apply in that context

Comment: not working. if i don't reuse the cells, all maps coordinates are misplaced.

Answer (score 1):

Sample of code

**MultiMap.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MultiMap : UIViewController
<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,MKMapViewDelegate>
{
    MKMapView *mapView;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *mainTableView;

@end
```

**MultiMap.m**

```
#import "MultiMap.h"

@interface MultiMap ()

@end

@implementation MultiMap

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
    self.title=@"Multi Map";
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return nil;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 200;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 4;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"multi";
    UITableViewCell *cell=nil;

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    mapView=[[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 25, 275, 150)];
    mapView.delegate=self;
    [mapView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [mapView setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    [cell addSubview:mapView];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{

}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@""];

    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

    return annotationView;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [_mainTableView release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

May you get help..

Comment: I don't think so. @OMGPOP

Comment: you just create a map view and set the frame in cellForRow. I call setupWithMessage in cellForRow as well.

Comment: thanks, but you need to check it first.. bcz I does not getting any problem in map.. @OMGPOP

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure your textView frame is 0. for the case the mapView doesn't show at accurate place additionally you can try following.

```
+ (CGRect)adjustTextView:(UITextView *)textView textViewSize:(CGSize)textViewSize extraView:(UIView *)extraView extraViewSize:(CGSize)extraViewSize entity:(id)entity {


    if (textView == nil || extraView == nil || CGSizeEqualToSize(textViewSize, CGSizeZero) || CGSizeEqualToSize(extraViewSize, CGSizeZero)) {
        CGSize targetSize;
        UIView *targetView;

        if (textView == nil || CGSizeEqualToSize(textViewSize, CGSizeZero)) {

            targetView = extraView;
            targetSize = extraViewSize;

        }
        else {
            targetView = textView;
            targetSize = textViewSize;
        }

        return [self adjustContentView:targetView size:targetSize entity:entity];

    }

    else {

        CGRect frame1 = [self adjustContentView:textView size:textViewSize entity:entity];
        CGRect frame2 = [self adjustContentView:extraView size:extraViewSize entity:entity];

        frame2.origin.y += frame1.size.height + OFFSET_BETWEEN_TEXTVIEW_EXTRAVIEW;
        extraView.frame = frame2;
        [[extraView superview] setNeedsLayout]; //Addition
        return CGRectMake(frame1.origin.x, frame1.origin.y, MAX(frame1.size.width, frame2.size.width), frame1.size.height + frame2.size.height + OFFSET_BETWEEN_TEXTVIEW_EXTRAVIEW);
    }
```

**UPDATE:** Or you can update the following

```
+ (CGRect)adjustContentView:(UIView *)contentView size:(CGSize) size entity:(id)entity {

float photoSideOffset = 60;
float topOffset = 30;

CGRect frame;
frame.size = size;

if ([DBHelper isMyEntity:entity]) {
    frame.origin.x = 320 - size.width - photoSideOffset;
}
else
{
    frame.origin.x = photoSideOffset;
}

for (id view in [[contentView superview] subviews])
{
    if (view != contentView)
    {
        if ([view respondsToSelector:@selector(frame)])
        {
            topOffset = (([view frame].origin.y + [view frame].size.height)<topOffset)?([view frame].origin.y + [view frame].size.height):topOffset;
        }
    }
}
if ((int)topOffset != 30)
{
    topOffset += OFFSET_BETWEEN_TEXTVIEW_EXTRAVIEW;
}
frame.origin.y = topOffset;
contentView.frame = frame;


if ([contentView isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
    [(UITextView *)contentView sizeToFit];
}

return contentView.frame;
}
```

**Also make sure you update the height of the cell accordingly using `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`**

Comment: both are not working. please note that the image messages (which are correct) are button images. if it can help?

Comment: can you post the frames you are getting from `CGRect frame1 = [self adjustContentView:textView size:textViewSize entity:entity];
        CGRect frame2 = [self adjustContentView:extraView size:extraViewSize entity:entity];`

Comment: I added a debugger screenshot in the question

Comment: For all the index paths the frame stays the same right?

Comment: yes all of the cells have the same frame (including the correct ones and incorrect ones)

Comment: i think the problem may be the text view frame, since only y coordinate is incorrect, and the text view frame only affects the y coordinate. but I tried to set it to cgsizezero and still the same problem